# Number of friendly pairs in vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, integer

I'm trying to write a function that accepts a vector of integers as a parameter and returns the number of friendly pairs that can be found in that vector. The function must not use any other auxiliary functions.

A pair of numbers is friendly if the sum of all divisors of one number (not counting itself) is equal to another number and vice versa.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
int Number_Of_Friendly_Pairs(std::vector<int>a) {
  std::vector<int>b;
  for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
    int sum_of_divisors = 0;
    for (int j = 1; j < a[i]; j++)
      if (a[i] % j == 0)
        sum_of_divisors += j;
    b.push_back(sum_of_divisors);
  }
  int number = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
    for (int j = i + 1; j < b.size(); j++)
      if (a[i] == b[j])
        number++;
  return number;
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<int>b{220, 1184, 284, 1210, 2620, 2924};
  std::cout << Number_Of_Friendly_Pairs(b);
  return 0;
}
```

Is my code completely accurate? For vector {220, 1184, 284, 1210, 2620, 2924} it gives correct output (which is 3). However, I'm not sure will it give correct output for every case.

Comment: _However, I'm not sure will it give correct output for every case._ Then write more tests!  You have designed your code in an eminently sensible way, so adding more test cases is easy.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: I would suggest passing the `a` parameter by const reference instead of by value: `int Number_Of_Friendly_Pairs(const std::vector<int> &a)` Also, the `for` loops that iterate through `a.size()` and `b.size()` should use `size_t` or better `std::vector<int>::size_type` rather than `int` for their loop counters. Or, use [range-for](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) loops for the outer loops that iterate `a`, at least.

Comment: *"The function must not use any other auxiliary functions."* -- I am willing to assume that you have no choice in the matter, but at the same time this is an unwise restriction that could lead me to conclude that this question falls in the "not useful" bucket. Not sure how I would rate the "research effort" since you have (only?) one test case. On the plus side, it does meet the "clear" criterion. So I'm kind of split on the upvote/downvote choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A pair of numbers is friendly if the sum of all divisors of one number (not counting itself) is equal to another number and **vice versa**.

However, the code only tests that some sum of divisors equal to some number. The vice versa part is sorely missing. For example, the code claims one friendly pair in `{7, 8}`.

You need to test for `(a[i] == b[j]) && (b[i] == a[j])`.

Comment: without that condition I get same result for {284,220} and {220,284}

Comment: Of course, because they _are_ amicable. Try `{7, 8}`, as I suggested.